# Traversing a game board using moves

Tags: javascript, arrays, optimization, replace, game-physics

I am having trouble figuring out a solution to traversing an array list that's treated as a board with walls and directions given. Basically you are given an array list like so:

```
  xxxxxxx
  x-g--xx
  x---xxx
  x-----x
  x--x--x
  x---1-x
  xxxxxxx
```

With a given list of moves:

```
uluudrll
```

The goal is to use the list of moves and make the according move based on the letter (u for up, d for down, etc.) given while you are traversing this board. You treat the x's as walls and g is your goal. The player is 1. I am using javascript for the code.

```
     if(move === 'd'){
        if(maze[row + 1][col] !== 'x'){
            maze[row + 1][col] = player;
            maze[row][col] = '-';
            count++;
        } else {
            if(move === 'd'){
                if(maze[row - 1][col] !== 'x'){
                    maze[row - 1][col] = player;
                    maze[row][col] = '-';
                    count++;
                } else if(maze[row][col + 1] !== 'x'){
                    maze[row][col + 1] = player;
                    maze[row][col] = '-';
                    count++;
                } else if(maze[row][col - 1] !== 'x'){
                    maze[row][col - 1] = player;
                    maze[row][col] = '-';
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my code for moving down and accommodating for the other movements (for example, if we read in a down movement, d, and it can't move because of a wall, the player will move to the other positions. I don't know whats going on with my code, but when I try to move in any other directions it won't work. Please help I'm pretty confused as to why game isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a pseudo code example on how to approach your game using Javascript

Take for example this array as your board:

```
arrayBoard = [["x","x","x","x"],["x","-","-","x"],["x","-","1","x"],["x","x","x","x"]];
```

If you want to move the player up for example first you need the player position `indexOf("1");` in this case is `arrayBoard[2][2];`

Then you know that `up` is the same position but on the second nested array `arrayBoard[[1][2];` and so on for the other directions.

To move the player you will have to replace the target postion with `"1"` and the previous position with `"-"`.

Now you will build your `function movement(){}` based on conditions like `if index of "1" + 1 !=="x" && === "g" then finish game`

So if you write your sequence as an array `seq = ["u","u","d","l","u"];` you will have to iterate over it and call your `function movement(){}` on each element.

By the way `indexOf()` in a multidimensional array will need `.map` or a loop to work.

Comment: thank you for answering this question and headache in a timely manner. I appreciate the help, but the problem that I am having is that when I set the condition it only moves the position once and thats it. I want it to go for every letter it sees.

Comment: Can you post all your code or a  [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)  and I will be happy to look at it. :)

Comment: yes i can [link](https://jsfiddle.net/8mtskb5x/1/embedded/result/). This class is reading in array of board and a list of moves, which is described above. Thank you!

Comment: Check your browser console cause your code is logging syntax errors. Also you if/else statement above uses `move==="d"`  for both the if and the if nested in the else statement

Comment: I believe the reason you're getting browsers errors because this isnt a driver class, but just a function class to handle the movement on the board.

Comment: Please check your if/else statement above since the conditions are the same

Comment: I changed that the second I saw that, but when I changed it, same results =/ I dont know what I'm doing wrong to make it literately go through the array list.

Comment: It's hard to figure it out from your fiddle, since I can't actually test it. Try console.log() each of your variables col,row,list and player to make sure that you are getting the results that you are looking for.

Comment: Here I have made a file that will output the result that we are looking for, but again it just doesn't iterate the fully through. Thanks for you help much appreciated! [link](https://jsfiddle.net/8mtskb5x/2/embedded/result/)

Comment: Here. Sorry for the delay [A fiddle with the player movement](http://jsfiddle.net/vh88knxq/)

Comment: Just checking back to see if you were able to get it working. :)

Comment: yes I did and your solution was very useful in my code. Thank you for your help!